# Execution Request Failed: When trying to get the list of Calendars

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I use this code to get the list of calendars but i get this error (.NET)

> Execution Request Failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default

I searched alot in google, but no use

How can i get the solution to get the Calendar List
params is of DataType OAuth2Parameters

```
GOAuth2RequestFactory rf = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("GoogleIntegration", applicationName, param);

CalendarService cs = new CalendarService(applicationName);
cs.RequestFactory = rf;
CalendarQuery fq = new CalendarQuery();
fq.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default");

CalendarFeed cf = cs.Query(fq);

ds = new DataSet();
dt = new DataTable();
dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "CalendarName";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

foreach (CalendarEntry ce in cf.Entries)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["CalendarName"] = ce.Title;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
gridcalendars.DataSource = ds;
gridcalendars.DataBind();
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Googles .net Client library?

Comment: You are using calendar v2 which is deprecated. Use calendar v3. here is the link for documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/